# PHP Wordpress redirect if not mobile and ignore specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the following code for redirecting non-mobile users to the desktop version of a website (a responsive theme is not an option), and it works perfectly until I need to access the WP Admin. How can I ignore the /wp-admin/ or wp-login.php page so I can still access the site if I am not already logged in?

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    if (!wp_is_mobile()) {
        // If not using mobile
        wp_redirect('https://my-desktop-site.com');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: ``is_admin()`` should work, i guess. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237659/check-if-i-am-in-the-admin-panel-wp-admin

Comment: @OMiShah - it's OK if I am already logged in, but if I try to access the wp-admin from a different computer, then the redirect kicks in and does its job. I need a check for the current page, I imagine. I just don't know PHP too well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_admin` determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page.

In no cases whatsoever will it fire on a `wp-login.php` as it is **NOT** an admin screen. Tho it will indeed fire upon an ajax request, therefore that case should be handle. `wp_doing_ajax()` determines whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.

`is_login()` [was recently announced for `6.1`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/09/11/new-is_login-function-for-determining-if-a-page-is-the-login-screen/), tho, for the moment we still need to rely on `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

```
<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {

    $request_uri = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( ! is_admin() && ! str_contains( basename( $request_uri ), 'wp-login.php' ) ) {

        if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {

            wp_redirect( 'https://...' );

            exit;

        }
    };

} );
```